# Is it safe to take "ownership" of C:/?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I have windows 10 education edition 1709 (**build:** 16299.125)

and I keep getting errors when trying to write to C:/python27 and directories of the like. so I want to take ownership of the whole C:/ directory. I just want to know if this is a safe action.

PS. I am doing this because windows BitLocker tells me:

```
This device can't use a Trusted Platform Module. Your administrator must 
set the "Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM" option in the "Require 
additional authentication at startup" policy for OS volumes
```

**My Question:**

I would like to enable BitLocker but the error it returns is above.
and I need to install python 2.7 and during installation, it cancels and reports "Permission denied, although I have granted UAC permission. I have tried reducing UAC level to 0 but that doesn't do anything. I am asking what I need to do in order to solve this issue as I am very restricted by windows. I have full administrative permissions.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Taking ownership of your C: drive won't solve that error message. And no, it's not safe. Don't do it.

Comment: is there a way for me to solve the "You need admin" issue? it's so annoying

Comment: Please start by rewriting your question to directly ask how to solve that problem. Tell us what you've tried and where your stuck.

Comment: I see, I will do that. BRB

Comment: Right click on the Python installer, and choose "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: I have tried this, believe it or not. that was one of the first things that came to mind.

Comment: You have education edition... is your PC university / school owned (and perhaps domain joined)? Have you asked the IT people to see if they may have some lock down in place (that you cannot bypass due to the group policy)?

Comment: Actually, long story: This is my very own PC but I wanted to Dualboot Ubuntu and accidentally deleted Windows 8.1's Partition, so I had to reinstall windows and because my school gives you windows 10 along with other software for free, I used The school provided windows. unfortunately, it was Education edition.

Comment: You are asking two different, and completely unrelated questions. They should be separate posts. The Bitlocker problem has nothing to do with permission issues installing Python.

Comment: Okay, I thought it did, because they both are related to permissions, so I thought that I would combine them. BTW, the python thing was an example of what kind of Filesystem problems I am experiencing. So, it's not just python. I had this problem many times before, but this was the most recent.

Comment: What errors are you actually getting? What are the details on it? What permission is being denied for what item? Taking ownership of all items on C:\ is going to be a problem because Windows really doesn't want to let go of some system files (for example).

Comment: Your question is super confusing. Are you asking about BitLocker? Or about Python? BitLocker isn’t concerned with filesystem permissions, it operates on the block level.

Comment: That I didn't know, I thought that because both had to do with permissions, there was an option to raise My administration level.

Comment: The Bitlocker error has nothing to do with permissions.  You should edit your question.  As others have said.  It’s confusing (even though the answer is known)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable a GPO called Require additional authentication at startup in the following path:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > BitLocker Drive Encryption > Operating System Drives

Make sure the “Allow BitLocker without a compatible TPM (requires a password or a startup key on a USB flash drive)” checkbox is enabled here.

[image]
Restart computer and turn on BitLocker again.

Comment: Okay, I understand, I will do this. Thank you

Comment: The window was a little difficult to find, but I got there